# Unable to register PJSIP in public IP Address. I have launched FreeSWITCH in the same IPAddress

Tags: pjsip, freeswitch

I have installed FreeSWITCH in a public IP address (it's a Virtual Machine).
While the FreeSWITCH is up, tried to register PJSIP as well but in the log below are the errors which are coming up.

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

SIP/2.0 400 Bad Request

Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to paste the full SIP log of pjsip and freeswitch server when this happens, Will try to help

Answer (score 0):

As PJSIP receiving 401 Unauthorized request, please check PJSIP send the Register again with the authentication details or not if not you first need to check with the PJSIP client. While registering what is the realm you are providing ?

400 Bad Request sends by freeswitch in case any mandatory headers were missing in the Request message. Please check on that.

to tell you the exact solution please give more details about your configuration and message details.